# How to get how jar is run?

Tags: java

I want to know, is there a way to get, whether jar is run from console using `java -jar`, or as executable file(thus using `javaw`). I'm creating a ssh client so I want to make use of `System.in`, `System.out`, `System.err` and `JTextPane` in one go.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Seems the question is, how to find out it a jar runs as a user with a console or as a service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `System.console()`. With javaw it'll return null.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking `How to determine if you're running from a JAR`, in which case check out this tutorial: [Determine if running from JAR](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0391.html)

Comment: No, not really, as it is going to be a .jar, i want to get, whether it is started using doubleclick, or a command.

Comment: Can you just add an argument flag and test in main? I.e. `java -jar jar_file console`

Answer (score 0):

In my Windows 8 with Java 8, `System.in` is automaticly closed if .jar was stared by double-click. With this demo:

```
public static void main(String[] main) throws Exception {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    if (scan.hasNextLine()) {
        System.out.println("from console");
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "From widows");
    }
    scan.close();
}
```

When double.clicked, `From windows` message is shown. However in console, you need to enter a line to see the `from console` message. It is not optimal, but at least something.